# Integrating using Green's Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, greens-theorem

**Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}xy\ dx $  where $\gamma$ is the  boundary of  the  square  with  vertices  $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$.**

Now **Green's Theorem**  says that $D$ be a  bounded  domain  with  piecewise smooth boundary  $\delta D$  and $P(x,y)$  and $Q(x,y)$  be  continuously  differentiable  functions  on  $D\cup {\delta D}$  then $$\int_{\delta D}P\ dx\ +Q\ dx\ \ =\ \ \int \int_{D}\left({{\delta Q}\over {\delta x}}-{{\delta P}\over {\delta y}}\right)dx\ dy$$

[image]

Now $Q$  is  already  $0$  here , we  have $P(x,y)=xy$ . $${{\delta P}\over {\delta y}}=x$$ giving us ,$$-\int \int_D x\ dx\ dy\\=-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x\ dx\ dy\\={{1}\over {2}} $$

Is it correct $?$

Actually  I am   not  sure  about  this  question  because  while  evaluating  the  double  integral  I  used  limits  as $(x\ varying\  0\rightarrow 1)$  and  $(y\ varying\ 0\rightarrow 1)$  and  got  same  value  on  both  sides but  in  a  worked  out  example  in  the   book about  a  triangle  with  vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$
[image]

they  did  the  calculation  as  $$\int_0^1\left[\int_0^{1-x}\ x\ dy\right]\ dx$$  i.e.  as  limits  they  used  *numbers*  for $x$  and *functions*  for  $y$ . So  I  do  not  understand   why or when  I  should  use  **numbers**  and  when  **functions**  as  limits  for  integration . Not  functions actually it  is  said  to  be  *parametrization* . I could  not  think  of  any  parametrization  for  this  square .

So what  I  indeed  need  is  to  know  how  to  choose  the  limits  for  double  integrals ,.  Explanations  are  most  welcome . Thanks.